# NSString get -characters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to get the characters of an NSString. Like this:

```
NSString *data;
const char * typein = [[data characters] UTF8String];
```

But obviously NSString won't respond to -characters. How do I get the characters of NSString?

thanks,
Elijah

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
for(int i =0 ;i<[myString length]; i++) {
  char character = [myString characterAtIndex:i];
}
```

or

```
NSString *str = @"astring";
const char *cString = [str UTF8String];
```

Comment: `-[NSString cString]` has been deprecated for ages; you should be using `-[NSString UTF8String]` or `-[NSString cStringUsingEncoding:]`.

Comment: i didn't know that thank you - i am going to modify my answer

Comment: Corrected, this is the better answer, though it doesn't explain why.  While `-UTF8String` works to get a buffer, you'll need to use `characterAtIndex:` if you want the fully composed unicode characters, some of which may be multiple bytes.

Comment: @mklfarha This [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/StringDrawing.html) actually recommends against using characterAtIndex to loop through NSString. I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to get a cString from the NSString just call `UTF8String` as you are already doing and then iterate the array.

Comment: Note that this gets a reference to a buffer containing the raw string.  As long as it is ASCII, it'll be one byte per character.  If it is unicode, it quite likely will contain characters that span multiple bytes.