# How can a program detect whether a string is a number or a character?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm working on a program that works with functions like `x + 3`. The program is able to calculate the equation and give the user a table of values. What I want to do next is to add the option to enter something like `x + a`. If the user puts the `x` value at `1`, for instance, I want it to be able to say `1 + a`. What I believe that I need in order to do this is to separate the string into an array, and then have it detect any characters that are alphabet (aside from `x`). I already know how to separate the string, but is there a way to detect an alphabet character without having to do something like a huge case switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare each character to the end points of the alphabet.

> ```
> char c = ...;
> if( ( c >= 'a' && c <='z' ) || ( c >='A' && c <= 'Z' ) )
>    it's a character;
> ```

(I don't know the objective C syntax)

(I'm so bad at formatting on this site it's not even funny)

Comment: No, but you could do something along the lines of: char c = string.charAt(0); (Again, don't know objective c) This will get you the first (and only) character of the string, and you can test that.

Comment: Okay, I think I can figure it out along the lines that you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886882/nsstring-get-characters, the syntax might be: char c = [myString characterAtIndex:i]; where i would be 0 in this case. (assuming you're using NSString).

Comment: I can also just use the compare method in NSString, since I can break up the string into one-character strings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the string manually, you could use a [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to examine the string components.